# isDialog() is not matching Dialog Fragment in Espresso

Tags: android, android-studio, android-testing, android-espresso

I have a suite of Android UI tests running using Cucumber-JVM and Espresso. However, I am facing issues with interacting with a dialog fragment.

Another fragment creates a dialog fragment on top with some view elements. When I try to check/interact with these, Espresso doesn't seem to find them at all in the view hierarchy. The view hierarchy it displays in the error message is that of the underlying fragment, and not the dialog fragment, which makes me think it is picking up an incorrect Root View.

To try to fix this, I added inRoot(isDialog()) into the statement:

```
onView(withText("Ok")).inRoot(isDialog()).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

This results in the following error message:

```
android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingRootException: Matcher 'is dialog' did not match any of the following roots: [Root{application-window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@f99cfec, window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@f99cfec, has-window-focus=true, layout-params-type=1, layout-params-string=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) sim=#20 ty=1 fl=#1810100 wanim=0x10303e5 needsMenuKey=2}, decor-view-string=DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1080, height=1794, has-focus=true, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}}, Root{application-window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@e5f9fb5, window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@e5f9fb5, has-window-focus=false, layout-params-type=1, layout-params-string=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) sim=#20 ty=1 fl=#1810100 wanim=0x10303e5 needsMenuKey=2}, decor-view-string=DecorView{id=-1, visibility=INVISIBLE, width=1080, height=1794, has-focus=true, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}}, Root{application-window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@c5e564a, window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@c5e564a, has-window-focus=false, layout-params-type=1, layout-params-string=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) ty=1 fl=#1810100 wanim=0x10303e5 needsMenuKey=2}, decor-view-string=DecorView{id=-1, visibility=INVISIBLE, width=1080, height=1794, has-focus=true, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}}, Root{application-window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@9b179bb, window-token=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@9b179bb, has-window-focus=false, layout-params-type=1, layout-params-string=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) ty=1 fl=#1810100 wanim=0x10303e5 needsMenuKey=2}, decor-view-string=DecorView{id=-1, visibility=INVISIBLE, width=1080, height=1794, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=false, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}}]
at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:580)
```

The code for creating the dialog:

```
public class ServiceItemFragment extends Fragment {
    ...
    public void showASampleDialog() {
        DialogFragment newFragment = SampleDialogFragment.newInstance(
                R.string.dialog_title);
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
    }
}
```

The code of the Dialog Fragment:

```
public class SampleDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static SampleDialogFragment newInstance(int title) {
        SampleDialogFragment frag = new SampleDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("title", title);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        int title = getArguments().getInt("title");

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle(title)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Positive click");
                            }
                        }
                )
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Negative click");
                            }
                        }
                )
                .create();
    }
}
```

Comment: For the time being I am working around the issue with UIAutomator:
    UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation());
    UiObject uiObject = device.findObject(new UiSelector().text("Ok"));
    try {
        uiObject.click();
    } catch (UiObjectNotFoundException e) {
         throw new RuntimeException("UI Object not found", e);
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To try to fix this, I added inRoot(isDialog()) into the statement:
>
> ```
>   onView(withText("Ok")).inRoot(isDialog()).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
> ```

It would be work if you were using `AlertDialog`, but not with `DialogFragment`

For this purpose the best solution is your actual workaround, I mean:

```
UIAutomator: UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation());
UiObject uiObject = device.findObject(new UiSelector().text("Ok"));
try {
    uiObject.click();
} catch (UiObjectNotFoundException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("UI Object not found", e);
}
```

Similar post and answer would be found here: [Android UI testing with Espresso on an AlertDialog inner views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37086596/android-ui-testing-with-espresso-on-an-alertdialog-inner-views)

Try also to ommit `inRoot()` matcher and write the test as simple as possible like:

```
onView(withText("Ok")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

This might be also useful: http://qathread.blogspot.com/2015/05/espresso-uiautomator-perfect-tandem.html

Comment: Ok, I will keep the workaround then. A bit disappointing if Espresso cannot work with DialogFragments at all.

Answer (score 3):

You can also match any root that is not a current activity:

`onView(withText("Ok")).inRoot(withDecorView(not(is(testRule.getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView())))).check(matches(isDisplayed())`

It also can be a devices animation issue. Make sure to disable it in the dev settings of your device.

Comment: That option seems to match some other root, as the test stalls and is terminated later due to inactive rootview. I have also disabled animations in developer settings.